# My variance equation is giving me a crazy output in Python

Tags: python

The point of this program is to take a random list and find the mean and variance of that list without the use of functions. My variance equation is giving me an output that is off by a few decimal places.

```
    variance = (mean - r)**2.0 + variance
```

An example of the output I'm getting is 8784462.44 when it should be 87844.6244.
I have no idea what is going wrong in my code.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could you please improve your code layout? there are too many newlines IMO and it's not clear what belongs to what `for` block

Comment: Use deeper indents. 4 spaces is the recommended size. This is very hard to read, and you messed up at least one indent.

Comment: As a comment on the code, my advice is to multiply by 1/len(random_list) instead of 1/100 -- inevitably the length of list will be changed to something else, so it's better to write the program so you don't have to make unnecessary changes.

Comment: Getting "8784462.44 when it should be 87844.6244" is not crazy. It's just off by two magnitudes.

Answer (score 6):

Variance = (1/n) times (sum of (x - mean(x))^2) -- you have only the summation; you forgot to multiply by 1/n.

Sometimes variance is defined as (1/(n - 1)) times (sum ...) -- I don't know what definition you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not correct:

```
variance = (mean - r)**2.0 + variance
```

You say you are calculating the numerator of the variance, and then printing that same `variance` variable without dividing by the number of numbers you are summing through (100 in your case). To get the variance (assuming you are treating the numbers as a "population"), you want:

```
variance = ((mean - r)**2.0)/100
```

from the equation for the population variance:

[image]

That accounts for your decimal point being off by 2 places in your example.

Comment: I think this doesn't really describe the problem. You can actually do the line `variance = (mean-r)**2.0 + variance`, given that later you do `variance = variance / 100`. The problem is simple, like Robert Dodier said, he just forgot to multiply by `1/n`.